# Uploading files using ASP.Net and IIS over SSL

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

We are having performance problems uploading file over SSL in our production site. I created a simplified example to try to isolate the problem and found that if I choose a file that is 7,599,000 (7.25MB) bytes or larger it takes over 2 minutes to upload the file. If I upload a file that is 7,598,999 (7.24MB) bytes or smaller it takes 7 seconds of less to upload the file. For some reason the 1 extra byte is making the process take almost 20 times longer.

Does anyone have an explanation of why this is happening or any solutions?

Here is the ASP.Net 4.5 code I am using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload1" />
        <asp:Button runat="server"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
            <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
        </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

The servers I am testing this on are Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5

Comment: are you perhaps working with the new "async await" keywords?

Comment: No, there is literally no code-behind in this example. It just posts the file and nothing is done with it.

Comment: Where are you hosting this service?

Comment: Amazon Web Services on a EC2 instance

Comment: Have u tried hosting locally, Azure, or dedicated instance?

Comment: Just curious: have you checked how different browsers behave ?

Comment: Could it not have something to do with the SSL implementation, try reposting it in a forum that deals with more complex technology implementations?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to solve this on Windows Server 2008 so I tried creating a new 2012 R2 instance and it works great. It must have been some configuration setting that I had.